# How to send 2D char pointer to a function for memory allocation?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<malloc.h>


void createDynamicArrayForChar(int dimension, char **ptr)
{
    ptr = (char**)malloc(dimension*sizeof(char*));

    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
    {
        ptr[i] = (char*)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
        ptr[i] = "value";
    }
}

int main()
{
    char **ptrArray;
    createDynamicArrayForChar(5, ptrArray);
    printf("%s", ptrArray[3]);


    getchar(); getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

It gives some errors when I try to compile this codes. How can I solve this problem? How to send 2D char pointer to a function in C?

Comment: Please [see why not to cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: `some errors`..it will be nice if you can share those with us. :)

Comment: @Bathsheba Good morning Sir !! I did not quite understand your comment. What is it actually? :)

Comment: @Bathsheba Sir, ( _I'm not very good at english, but as per my understanding_ ) I'll take this as a compliment. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, as per the present code, I see two issues.

1. You're passing `ptrArray` to the function and trying to allocate memory inside the function. Please be aware, C uses pass by value for function argument passing, so, if you want to allocate memory to `ptrArray` and expect that to be *refeclted*  back to the caller, without `return`ing,  you'll be needing to pass a pointer to that `ptrArray.
2. in the code

   ```
   ptr[i] = (char*)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
   ptr[i] = "value";
   ```

   You're leaking memory. Once you've allocated memory using `malloc()`, you should use `strcpy()` to copy the data into the allocated memory.

That said, some advice:

1. Please [see why not to cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.
2. `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1 in `C`. Using that as a multiplier is not required.
3. Always check the success of `malloc()` before using the returned pointer.

Comment: Thanks Sourav, can you edit my codes and show us? Because I didn't understand your first statement completely. I'm trying to learn more English.

Comment: It gives "error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'ptrArray' used".

Answer (score 2):

You probably need this (no error checking and not debugged code):

```
void createDynamicArrayForChar(int dimension, char ***ptr)
{
    *ptr = (char**)malloc(dimension*sizeof(char*));

    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
    {
        (*ptr)[i] = (char*)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
        strcpy((*ptr)[i],"value");
    }
}
```

or

```
char **createDynamicArrayForChar(int dimension)
{
    char **ptr = (char**)malloc(dimension*sizeof(char*));

    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
    {
        ptr[i] = (char*)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(ptr[i],"value");
    }

    return ptr;
}

int main()
{
    char **ptrArray;
    ptrArray = createDynamicArrayForChar(5);
    ...
```

Read also Sourav Ghosh's answer.

Comment: An error of my codes is "error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'ptrArray' used".

Comment: @Hakan you should update your question instead of posting this here. Do you understand why you get this error ?